# How to write wait condition for browser.title()?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, browser, automation, protractor

I'm looking for a wait condition to get the browser title. Currently, i use `browser.getTitle()` to get the browser title. Somehow, my script times out waiting to get the browser title. I can't use `browser.sleep` in this case. How do i achieve this by using `browser.wait()` condition?

Any help with be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this angularjs (instead of angular)?

Comment: Yup. it's angularjs. modified it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use case for the [titleIs ExpectedCondition](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.titleIs). Could you give it a try?

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.titleIs('foo'), 5000, 'Title not "foo" after 5 seconds');
```

Comment: This works too. Probably a recommended solution. thanks for your time in answering this! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function waitForTitle(expectedTitle: string, time: number) {
    return browser.wait(() => {
        return browser.getTitle().then((currentTitle) => {
            return currentTitle === expectedTitle;
        });
    }, time);
}
```

You just need to remember that time is given in ms.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution and post my response.